# Server Tag Options

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I've noticed that people asking SQL-Server questions sometimes tag their questions with the SQL and [Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server) tags or just the Server tag rather than the SQL-Server tag.  Often the question isn't about SQL at all and Server doesn't necessarily add any information unless it means SQL-Server.  As of this post there are 14 questions tagged [Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server).  Ten of them are SQL-Server questions most without the SQL-Server tag.  The other four questions don't deal with SQL-Server, and none really benefit from the tag.  It seems like something should be done, but I'll leave it to community to decided what is best.   Here are some options.

- Make the Server tag a synonym for SQL-Server.  This would help 10 questions and hurt four today.  In the future it would probably have the same ratio of benefit/determent.
- Manually remove/replace the tag.  This would be more work not just today, and would require continual modification of questions.  On the other hand every question would get the correct tag(s).
- Ban the Server tag.  I don't know if this is even possible, but it would keep the tag from cluttering up questions in which it is not helpful and promote selection of the better SQL-Server tag.  I suspect such a thing doesn't exist because of the confusion it would bring to a user trying to add it to their question.

If you have an alternative suggestion, please post it.  I suppose "Do Nothing" is also an option.

Comment: Are there any cases you can think of where `server` would be an appropriate tag not meaning SQL Server?

Comment: @Nick There are situations in which it would not be appropriate for the tag to mean SQL Sever.  For those situations the Server tag is simply not appropriate at all.  For example, dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7185/, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7187/, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/, and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7940/

Answer (score 7):

I think the synonym for sql-server sounds like the best option. Vote this up if you like this idea, or comment if you want one of the others. I'll do this substitution tomorrow.

What I'm curious about is the "Sql" tag... If there are no dissenting opinions.

Comment: yeah, sounds best option. We can correct it anyway

Comment: That was my opinion, but I didn't want to bias the discussion too much.

Comment: @LeighRiffel fortunately I get to bias it a lot. :D

Answer (score 0):

[server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server) no longer exists.

There is no history available that I can see, so I assume the tag was manually edited out from the questions it appeared on, and was therefore deleted by the system.

It has never been recreated, which is a good thing.